# Generate non repeating random number within range in Java

Tags: java, random, non-repetitive

I want to generate random numbers within the range 1 to 4, 4 including.
Here is my code:

```
int num = r.nextInt(4) + 1;  //r is instance of Random.
```

However, I am running the above code in a loop and don't want repeating random number.
What happens now is often I am getting:
    `1,1,1,2,3,1,4,2,2,1,4,2,4,4,2,1,4,3,3,1,4,2,4,1` as my output.

Here, though the numbers are random within the range(1-4), but often repeated like the number "1"in the first 3 iterations.

What I am looking for is a way to get non repeating random number within the loop.
One simple way I know is of keeping the last random number before current iteration and compare, but I am sure there must be better solution to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would not really be random anymore would it?  (xkcd post ect ect)

Comment: well, after you generate, say, `4,1,3,2`, you're going to have repeats... how do you want to handle that case?

Comment: also, I agree with collection.shuffle(), but would it be a fine idea to call collection.shuffle() in every iteration and is that fool proof  for non repetitive nature ?

Comment: I am fine by `4,1,3,2` what i don't want is `1,1,3,4,2,2`. The same numbers appearing side by side.

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, exactly.

Comment: So `4,1,3,4,1,2,3,2` would be ok too?

Comment: Second question on this topic in two days.  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @CPerkins Not for me, I am trying to write a board game with 4 players . Need the random for auto play :p

Comment: Is randomness really a good strategy in your game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `random.nextInt(range-1)` and then map that number to the output number with a function that excludes the previous number:

```
public class Test {
  private final Random random = new Random();
  private final int range;
  private int previous;

  Test(int range) { this.range = range; }

  int nextRnd() {
    if (previous == 0) return previous = random.nextInt(range) + 1;
    final int rnd = random.nextInt(range-1) + 1;
    return previous = (rnd < previous? rnd : rnd + 1);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Test t = new Test(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) System.out.println(t.nextRnd());
  }
}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Would keeping a previous value for compare would be much lighter in comparison to Collection.shuffle ? If yes, then I think this solution suits me the best.

Comment: This could produce a number which is max+1

Comment: @PeterLawrey But I start with a random number chosen from a set that is one less in size than the number of allowed integers. If in any doubt, please run it to convince yourself.

Comment: @ashish.gd This is definitely preferred to shuffling a whole array of numbers at each step.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It actually can't, he shifts the whole top of the range, i.e. If previous is 2, he takes the range `1 2 3` and shifts the top to be `1 3 4` by adding one to the higher numbers, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

As you have more numbers than you have to choice from you have to repeat some numbers. All you can do is minimise the number of immediate repeats.

One way to do this is to use Collections.shuffle which allow you to have numbers in a random order, without repeats and do this each time.  You could prevent the last N value being repeated.

To stop consecutive repeating numbers you can reduce the range and use modulus.

```
int n = 0, max = 4;
Random rand = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
   n = (n + rand.nextInt(max-1)) % max;
   int numToUse = n + 1;
   // use this number.
}
```

This work as there is really only `max-1` possible values as you are excluding the last value used.

Comment: I think he just wants to prevent `3,2,2,3`, `2,3,2,3` is ok, shuffle is overkill

Comment: So adding 1 - 4 in a collection and then calling Collections.shuffle in every iteration, to pick the first element should solve my problem ?

Comment: @durron597 Yes, I just don't want same numbers side by side and trying my best to avoid shuffle :(

Comment: @ashish.gd Calling shuffle every time you have used all the values in the list

Comment: @PeterLawrey Using up all values is fine since I am going to use this in a loop. All I want is say if there are 10 iterations in my loop, I will obviously have 10 random numbers between 1 - 4 range. Agreed that they will get repeated. But I just don't want then repeating in sequence i.e. `2,3,2,3` is OK but not `2,2,3,3`.

Comment: PeterLawrey It's actually not, now that I'm not misreading it anymore, @MarcoTopolnik's answer is far better than mine as it doesn't need to loop. That's why I deleted it

Answer (score 1):

There is no "better" answer.
You are getting a *random* number. Check this line:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

this *could* be perfectly random. 
So I propose you describe a better requirement.
Do you want always a next number that is different from the previous? Do you want a maximum of duplicates in a special rang? lets say within 6 consecutive numbers, every number is allowed to occur twice?

If you bring such a requirement we might be able to help you. otherwise we can just say: what you seeing is really random :)

Comment: Like `Random random = new Random(441287210);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        System.out.print(random.nextInt(10)+" ");
    }` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm:

```
initialize an array A[4] with the numbers 1-4
set a counter Acnt, the effective size of A. Initialize to 4
for i in 1 to length(output sequence)
   choose a random integer X from 0 to Acnt -1
   save A[X] to your output sequence
   swap(A[X],A[Acnt - 1])
   Acnt--
   if(Acnt == 0) Acnt = lengh(A)
```

Imagine A is a bag of balls with the numbers 1-4.  Each iteration of your loop, you remove a ball. Rather than actually deleting from the array, which is expenisve, you simply hide the ball at the end of the array. When you decrement the number of balls in the bag (Acnt), the next ball you select comes from the non-hidden balls.

When you have no more balls to select, you unhide the balls by resetting the count of balls in your bag back to the full count.

This is basically the standard shuffle algorithm.

**Edit:** Rereading the question, I see now he allows repeats after only 1 number instead of the whole sequence, in which case it all you need to do to modify this is change if (Acnt == 0) to if(Acnt == length(A) - 1).

Comment: This looks similar to what Collections.shuffle does.

Comment: It is probably exactly the same.  The advantage of doing inline is that he get the numbers one at a time.